# Enable caching of analysis results to reduce analysis rerun at start

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Everytime I open up a Python source in VSCode, I see that it runs analysis again; which takes a while to complete. Is there some kind of caching of analysis results' supported in VSCode? I tried looking around in the VSCode python plugin docs and also tried setting the Cache folder path in Settings -> Python -> Analysis but that didn't help; analysis was still being run on startup. How can I ask VSCode to cache the results of analysis for reuse later on?

Comment: The setting `python.analysis.cacheFolderPath` lets you specify a folder to cache in